Overall ANCOVA not significant but post-hoc pairwise comparison are
I have the following problem:
I run a ANCOVA with three time-points and 3 covariates; no factors (groups).
My overall ANCOVA is not significant. But all my post-hoc (Bonferroni-adjusted) pairwise comparison's of the different timepoints are (even highly significant).
I tested the model again with ANOVA, then the overall model was significant again. I tested the model three times again with each of the covariates separately, everytime, the overall ANCOVA was not significant again (whether the covariate was significant or not).
I have a rather small sample size, but it is > 30.
I have another 5 ANCOVAs in the same manner (different outcome measurements), and the same repeated for all of them. So the problem must lay in my covariates.
What do I do now?

Only run Anova without covariates?
Preffered: Run the ANCOVA and report both overall ANCOVA (not significant) and pairwise (significant)? IF I do that, how can I argue and what would the conclusion be?


How are you accounting for the repeated measures? Are you doing RM-ANOVA and RM-ANCOVA? I would prefer a multilevel model, but you have to deal with the repeats somehow, or you are violating the assumption of independent errors.

Thank you, yes I am running a repeated-measures Ancova !

In general, if your timepoint-timepoint comparisons are theoretically predicted and you planned them in advance, the omnibus test (in your case, the overall ANCOVA) does not need to be significant for you to conduct the pairwise comparisons.
See, for instance, here, here, here, and here.
If you designed your study thinking the covariate needs to be included, I don't think you should take it away from the model. You can run the ANCOVA and conduct the planned post-hoc comparisons between time points despite the omnibus effect being non-significant.
However, it might be relevant for the interpretation of the results that the omnibus effect disappears when you add the covariate. I wonder what happens if you include an interaction between the time variable and the covariate?
